# How do I toggle status by entering the id of that field?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, rest, websocket

I have 3 columns name, status and autogenerated id. I want to toggle the status from off to on (or vice versa) by entering the id. How should I do that?

I am using React for frontend, Node.js for backed and mongodb database.

`<TextField label="Light Id" value={id} onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)} /> <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleStatus}> Toggle </Button>`

What should I write in the handleStatus function and in the api call?